# Screenshots of error page in selenium web driver with date of its occurence and page or link on which it has occured

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My scenario is I'm getting same error page on few button/link click on my website.I have a sample of code for taking screenshot according to the date timestamp, but I also want to fetch its occurence on which button or link click event it occured and want to append that event name to the screenshot file.
Please help out.
Thanks in advance

As of now this is what I have.

```
try{
  My code where the error occures on button click
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
            File scrn=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

            // extracting date for folder name.
            SimpleDateFormat sdfDate1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");//dd/MM/yyyy
            Date now1 = new Date();
            String strDate1 = sdfDate1.format(now1);

            // extracting date and time for snapshot file
            SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss");//dd/MM/yyyy
            Date now = new Date();
            String strDate = sdfDate.format(now);

            String filefolder="D:/Home/Snapshot/"+strDate1+"/";  // create a folder as snapshot in  your project directory

            // Creating folders and files
            File f = new File(filefolder+strDate+".jpeg");

            FileUtils.copyFile(scrn, new File(f.getPath()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the entire code for the screenshot in a method, like `take_screenshot` and put it in a common place like and pass it one argument with the name of the even where it occurred.

```
try {
    // some action which causes an error
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MyLib.TakeScreenshot("click button")  // argument name, 'action' for example
    // do other things for error handling
}
```

And `MyLib.TakeScreenshot` has the code you've put above. For the line

```
// Creating folders and files
File f = new File(filefolder+strDate+".jpeg");
```

Change that to:

```
File f = new File(filefolder + strDate + action + ".jpeg"); //action name added to filename
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Define path for Screenshot file.
 */
public String getScreenshotSavePath() {

    String className = this.getClass().getName();
    File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator+"screenshots"+File.separator + className + File.separator);
    dir.mkdirs();
    return dir.getAbsolutePath();
}


/**
 * Take Screenshot on failure.
 */
public void getScreenshot() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
    String date = sdf.format(new Date());
    String url = driver.getCurrentUrl().replaceAll("[\\/:*\\?\"<>\\|]", "_");
    String ext = ".png";
    String path = getScreenshotSavePath().toString()+ File.separator + date + "_" + url + ext;

    try {
        if (driver instanceof TakesScreenshot) {
            File tmpFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            org.openqa.selenium.io.FileHandler.copy(tmpFile, new File(path));
            auto_logs.error("Captured Screenshot for Failure: "+path);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add these methods in your base class, so that you can call them in your test case's catch(){} routine.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create a proxy class that implements the WebDriver interface (or only the methods you need) and has the real WebDriver object as a constructor argument. This way you can use the methods of the proxy object, which will take a screenshot with information about the event that threw the exception.

```
public class WebDriverProxy {
   private WebDriver driver;

   public WebDriverProxy(WebDriver driver) {
         this.driver = driver;
   }

   public void clickLink (String linkText) {
      try{ 
        driver.click(By.linkText(linkText);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        this.takeScreenshot(linkText);
        throw e;
      }
   }

   private void takeScreenshot(String event) {
      /** take the screenshot and save it with String event in the filename **/
   }
}
```